# Find the max value in the last digit

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySQL 5.5. I am facing a problem on how to find the max value in the last digit.

For example below the table, I want to get the max value is detected the last digit. The result should be `100-1-15`

```html
Table name: abc
+----+------------+
| id | code       |
+----+------------+    
| 1  |   100-1-1  |
| 2  |   100-1-2  |
| 3  |   100-1-15 |
| 4  |   100-1-6  |
| 5  |   100-1-3  |
| 6  |   100-1-5  |
| 7  |   100-1-9  |
+----+------------+
```

I am using below the SQL query, but doesn't work:

```html
SELECT id,max(code) FROM abc;
```

Hope someone can guide me how to solve it and can get the max code is `100-1-15`. Thanks.

Comment: Does all `code` values have the same prefix `'100-1-'` and differs in last group only? if not then show an example with different prefixes and desired output for such data.

Comment: Not same. I just want to grab last digit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT *
from abc
order by SUBSTRING_INDEX(code, '-', -1) + 0 desc
limit 1
```

Comment: Thanks, @juergen d. I have the same issue as this SQL query in other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64060060/substring-index-sort-the-number-with-the-symbol-and-the-character 
If you have time, you can see it. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
Select 
   id,
   code
from abc
order by max(CAST(SUBSTR(code, 7, LENGTH(code)-6) AS SIGNED)) 
limit 1;
```