# SUBSTRING_INDEX sort the number with the symbol and the character

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, mysql-5.5

I am used MySQL 5.5 to do my query. I am facing the problem to sort the number with `-` in front of the character. Below is my example table and I want to sort the column `number_with_name` with the condition:

Table name: test123

```html
+-----+--------------------+
| id  | number_with_name   |
+-----+--------------------+    
| 1   |   200-2 David      |
| 2   |   200-2-2 Peter    |
| 3   |   200-2-2-9 James  |
| 4   |   200 Robert       |
| 5   |   200-2-3 Siva     |
| 6   |   200-2-5 Denny    |
| 8   |   200-2-9 Rose     |
| 9   |   200-3 Kiki       |
| 10  |   100-3-2 Viva     |
| 11  |   100-3-15 Proton  |
| 12  |   100-3-6 Saga     |
| 13  |   100 Liver        |
| 14  |   100-3 Shawn      |
| 15  |   100-3-5-1 Kola   |
| 16  |   100-3-5-8 Frankie|
| 17  |   100-3-5 Jala     |
+----+---------------------+
```

I want the expected result like below the table:

```
+-----+--------------------+
| id  | number_with_name   |
+-----+--------------------+  
| 13  |   100 Liver        |
| 14  |   100-3 Shawn      |
| 10  |   100-3-2 Viva     |
| 17  |   100-3-5 Jala     |
| 15  |   100-3-5-1 Kola   |
| 16  |   100-3-5-8 Frankie|
| 12  |   100-3-6 Saga     |
| 11  |   100-3-15 Proton  |
| 4   |   200 Robert       |
| 1   |   200-2 David      |
| 2   |   200-2-2 Peter    |
| 3   |   200-2-2-9 James  |
| 5   |   200-2-3 Siva     |
| 6   |   200-2-5 Denny    |
| 8   |   200-2-9 Rose     |
| 9   |   200-3 Kiki       |
+----+---------------------+
```

I have used below the SQL to sort, but it doesn't work.

```html
SELECT * from test123 order by SUBSTRING_INDEX(number_with_name, '-', -1) + 0 asc
```

Akira answer result for real test:

[image: Output]
Hope someone can guide me on how to sort like this case. Thanks.

Comment: What's `SQL 5.5`? `SUBSTRING_INDEX` is not a SQL Server function, maybe MySQL?

Comment: Yes. You are right. Is MySQL. I have edited it. Thanks.

Comment: @dnoeth Can you help me on this question?

Comment: Provide sample data as INSERT INTO, not as a table.

Comment: What's your version of MySQL? 5.5 is an ancient version

Comment: This is tricky. I see that you want to have `100-3-6 Saga` before `100-3-15 Proton`, because 6 comes before 15. This means that we must separate all numbers of a number chain and treat them each numerically in the `ORDER BY`. It may help, if there are restrictions that apply, e.g. "no number can be more than four digits" or "the number chain can be no more than four numbers deep". Can you name such restrictions?

Comment: Seeing your edit and additional question, it seems you merely copied Akinas query without trying to understand it. This is a very bad idea. Look at the query, understand it and then adapt it if possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM test
ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(number_with_name, '-', 1) + 0
       , CASE WHEN LENGTH(number_with_name) - LENGTH(REPLACE(number_with_name, '-', '')) > 0
              THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(number_with_name, '-', 2), '-', -1) + 0
              ELSE 0 
              END
       , CASE WHEN LENGTH(number_with_name) - LENGTH(REPLACE(number_with_name, '-', '')) > 1
              THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(number_with_name, '-', 3), '-', -1) + 0
              ELSE 0 
              END
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=bebd0bf45c05f7adcbe0228ee955be85)

Comment: This is a good approach, but only works if the maximum depth of the number chain is known. In the example the maximum depth is four numbers (e.g. `100-3-5-8 Frankie`). In your query, you only sort by the first three, however, which is why you can get a wrong order for `100-3-5-1 Kola` and `100-3-5-8 Frankie`.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner If somebody has a task with indefinite depth (in any sense) he must update the server to the actual version firstly - if not then he must use SPs, not queries.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a more generalizable approach.  The idea is to treat the components as *strings* rather than as *numbers*.  You can order numeric strings as numbers by first ordering on the length and then on the value alphabetically.

Because prefixes don't matter when sorting strings, you can do this with just `substring_index()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM test
ORDER BY LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(number_with_name, ' ', 1), '-', 1)) ASC,
         SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(number_with_name, ' ', 1), '-', 1),
         LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(number_with_name, ' ', 1), '-', 2)) ASC,
         SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(number_with_name, ' ', 1), '-', 2),
         LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(number_with_name, ' ', 1), '-', 3)) ASC,
         SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(number_with_name, ' ', 1), '-', 3),
         LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(number_with_name, ' ', 1), '-', 4)) ASC,
         SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(number_with_name, ' ', 1), '-', 4)
```

This sorts up to four components.  The only trick here is the nested `substring_index()`.  This limits the comparison only to the initial number, which seems to be the intent.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=9704e7e6497f485da79d1c1db910af79) is a db<>fiddle.